# zeros of the derivative of the spherical Bessel function

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, bessel-functions

I make reference to the function in Scipy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.spherical_jn.html#scipy.special.spherical_jn). I want to calculate the zeros of the derivative of the function j'_n(x). Any propositions for how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in scipy function `scipy.optimize.brentq` to find the roots. An example usage is

```
import scipy.optimize
from scipy.special import spherical_jn

def sphericalBesselBrent(x, n, derivative):
    return spherical_jn(n, x, derivative=derivative)

x0 = scipy.optimize.brentq(sphericalBesselBrent, 0.5, 5, args=(2, True))
print(x0)
```

Where we need to define some wrapper function `sphericalBesselBrent` around the scipy bessel function to match the function template required by `brentq`. This returns a single root between `0.5` and`5`. If you need more roots, you would need to iterate over ranges to search for roots. `a` and `b` must be different signs.